# Using pop for removing element from 2D array

Tags: python, list

In the below random array:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],
     [6,7,8,9]]
```

Could you please tell me how to remove element at a specific position. For example, how would I remove `a[1][3]`?

I understand `list.pop` is used for only list type DS here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple, just pop on the list item.

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3,4], [6,7,8,9]]
>>> a[1].pop(3)
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-del_stmt) to *remove* an item at a specific index:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3,4], [6,7,8,9]]
>>> del a[1][3]
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
>>>
```

`list.pop` should only be used when you need to save the value you just removed.

Comment: If we remove one element from a column , for example , from bottom of a column, then how to adjust the element in that column ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the three method:

1. Remove
2. Pop
3. del

a = [[1,2,3,4],
     [6,7,8,9]]

1- Remove a[1].remove(a[1][3])

2- Pop a[1].pop(3)

3-Del del a[1][3]

Comment: To make your answer clearer, have a look at using code blocks - see the 'help' option while writing/editing your answer.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, 
`a[1].remove(9)`
removes a[1][3]

[link to python list document](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)