# Pop() an element of a list in the list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists. I want to pop() an element say from the second list in the list of lists.
Here is an example:

```
>>> list1=[1,2]
>>> list2=[3,4]
>>> listoflists=[list1, list2]
```

so, printing listoflists gives me:

```
>>>listoflists
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

I want to pop, say, the first element of the second list in listoflists, i.e., 3.

```
>>>listoflists.pop([1][0])
```

gives me the following error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-db5dc303028d>", line 1, in <module>
    listoflists.pop([0][1])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `listoflists[1].pop()` ?

Comment: I love the effort people puts in solving their problems before asking here on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listoflists[1].pop(0)
```

listoflists[1] equals list2

so

listoflists[1].pop(0) equals  list2.pop(0)

Comment: This works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the correct way to pop 2d arrays is like this

```
list1=[1,2]
list2=[3,4]
listoflists=[list1, list2]

print listoflists

listoflists[0].pop(0)//correct way to pop

print listoflists
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553578/using-pop-for-removing-element-from-2d-array) is another post similar to yours on poping 2d lists that also might be of use.