# Deleting a string from a one list with strings/numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list that looks like this -

```
item1,5,1,648,16,10,0,3,5,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0
item2,3,1,29,3,6,0,0,3,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0
item3,4,1,2388,20,8,2,0,3,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
item4,6,3,0,0,1,0,0,5,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0
```

What would be the best way of deleting the "item" part of the list?

I've tried

```
del list[j][0]
```

But then I get "TypeError: 'str' object doesn't support item deletion"

I've tried

```
list[j].remove(list[j][0])
```

But then I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'

Pop doesn't seem to work either - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'

Any ideas?

EDIT:
So I've read in a list -

```
data = open("flags.features", 'r').readlines()
```

Then just split each line -

```
for i in data:
    input_list.append(i.split('\n')[0])
```

With an output of -

```
['item1,5,1,648,16,10,0,3,5,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0',         'item2,3,1,29,3,6,0,0,3,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0', 'item3,4,1,2388,20,8,2,0,3,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0', 'item4,6,3,0,0,1,0,0,5,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0', 'item5,3,1,0,0,6,3,0,3,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete empty strings from a 2d list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57983240/how-to-delete-empty-strings-from-a-2d-list)

Comment: Is it 1D or 2D list? It seems like you are having a 1D list.

Comment: @Kongvungsovanreach added what my list actually looks like

Comment: it is a 1D list. So if you access by list[j], you will get a string. You cannot use any list methods on the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
data = open("flags.features", 'r').readlines()
input_list = []

for i in data:
    input_list.append(",".join(i.split('\n')[0].split(",")[1:]))
```

This outputs

```
['5,1,648,16,10,0,3,5,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0',
 '3,1,29,3,6,0,0,3,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0',
 '4,1,2388,20,8,2,0,3,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0',
 '6,3,0,0,1,0,0,5,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0']
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
my_list = [x.split(",") for x in my_list]
my_list[j].pop(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
list[j].pop(1) #the 1 can be replaced with any number
```

This will index the list then pop the item in that list off.

This question is also very similar to:
[Using pop for removing element from 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553578/using-pop-for-removing-element-from-2d-array)

Comment: Yes, I've tried that but I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'

Comment: @tobytobias could you show the full list and code? That could help.

Comment: I added a bit more detail in the post @Blue Robin

Comment: Does appending it without the newline work? @tobytobias

Comment: So you're saying instead of split at \n, I change how I input it, so it doesn't have the Item part?

Comment: @tobytobias I'm not sure. But other answers seem very useful.

Comment: Yep, I've figured it out, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome @tobytobias I tried my best